# PHP while loop different images

Tags: php, html, while-loop

Okay let me clarify everything.

Chars table looks like http://prntscr.com/9v8jiv .

Here is the standard html

```
<div id="characterone">
  <h1 class="charactername">Test_Name</h1>
  <p class="characterstats">DOB: 12/01/1992</p>
  <p class="characterstats">Origin: Mexican</p>
  <p class="characterstats">Time in Los Santos: 56</p>

  <button class="choosebutton">Choose</button>
</div>

<div id="charactertwo">
   <h1 class="charactername">Angelo_Damce</h1>
   <p class="characterstats">DOB: 12/01/1992</p>
   <p class="characterstats">Origin: American</p>
   <p class="characterstats">Time in Los Santos: 26</p>

   <button class="choosebutton">Choose</button>
</div>

<div id="characterthree">
    <h1 class="charactername">Moemen_Walid</h1>
    <p class="characterstats">DOB: 12/01/1992</p>
    <p class="characterstats">Origin: American</p>
    <p class="characterstats">Time in Los Santos: 26</p>

    <button class="choosebutton">Choose</button>
</div>
```

All I want to do is, to select someone's logged in characters and then he sees the 3 in front of him and then he chooses,

I began by normaling querying them

```
$getchars = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `characters` where Username = '".$user."'") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    $check = mysqli_num_rows($getchars);
```

Now I need to find a way so for every char the mysql query find, to be echo'ed or written in the html up.

Eg: echo ''.$row[1]["Name"].' ';
but in each div there should be a different echo

```
'.$row[2]["Name"].'
^ But of course this code isn't real. just trying to explain.
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the `switch` statement? Or a dictionary?

Comment: You can use if condition

Comment: I 'd prefer knowing how to echo the 3 characters matching alone.
Because each char is in a different div, any ideas?

Comment: Can you please post a sample data and output you expect?

Comment: What does what you're echo-ing have to do with the data in the result array?  It's not really clear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Let me clarify,

Now I used
$getchars = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `characters` where Username = '".$user."'") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));

to get my chars.

they are 3 chars, I need to echo each char in a different div
  <div id="characterone">
  <div id="charactertwo">
  <div id="characterthree">

Comment: But what does the char data look like and can a user have more than one char?

Comment: What is the data input?

Comment: data input of that chars are simple I will 
mysql fetch the $getchars

and will echo $row["name"];
Etc, but that will just echo 1 character, I need to echo each char in its own div,.

Comment: So this $rowget["Character"] itself will contain all the three characters?

Comment: yep, so I need a way to fetch the 3 at once and echo 1 by 1 like

echo $row["name"][1]; Or then an array , IDK, I just need help :(

Comment: Can you please show a sample value of $rowget["Character"] ?

Comment: Edited up ^ in the main post

Comment: What is the value of $rowget["Character"]? What are the actual characters that are inside that variable?

Comment: Ignore that, it was getting the Username from the sessions and then copying it.just check the last 4 lines.

Comment: Ok, so what are the 3 different chars? Can you put up the structure of your characters table?

Comment: Sorry Your issue is really confusing, Not sure what is the output you are expecting? Atleast can you show a screenshot of the data or anything else? Please be clear as much as possible.

Comment: I updated the whole post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Here is the complete answer for your question. Just replace the Name and Time Column names with the correct Column names in the database.

```
$i = 1;
while($rowget = mysqli_fetch_array($getchars))
        {
            $id1 = 'characterone';
            $id2 = 'charactertwo';
            $id3 = 'characterthree';
            if($i<4){
               echo'<div id="'.${'id'.$i}.'">';
               echo '<h1 class="charactername">'.$rowchar["Name"].'</h1>
              <p class="characterstats">DOB: '.$rowchar["Birthdate"].'</p>
              <p class="characterstats">Origin: '.$rowchar["Origin"].'</p>
              <p class="characterstats">Time in Los Santos: '.$rowchar["Skin"].'</p>            
              <button class="choosebutton">Choose</button>';
               echo '</div>';
            }
$i++;
}
```

Comment: You saved my life <3

Thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

just use a counter

```
$i=1;
while($rowget = mysqli_fetch_array($getchars)) {
    $charpost = $rowget["Character"];
    echo' <img src=$i.png> ';
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Well yeah thanks, that is the answer of what I asked, but I meant to say that I got 3 different divs, and I need to echo each char in each div. am using
 $checkkey = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Username FROM accounts where ID = '".$id."' AND Password = '".$key."'") or die(mysqli_error());
 $check = mysqli_num_rows($checkkey);